# WordPress short hand / code image location

Tags: wordpress

is there a short hand way to link images in WordPress ... I find myself having to type out

```
http://domain.com/cms/wp-content/themes/site_theme/simgs/structure/categories.png
```

in order to get the image to load. I'd like to do something like

```
<img src="simgs/structure/categories.png" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using template tags rather than hardcoding URLs in Wordpress. An example, using your URL above, would be:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/simgs/structure/categories.png" />
```

Please be aware that I'm not sure whether the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function returns a trailing slash or not so you may have to glimpse at your template's outputted source to find out.

Comment: If you're reusing the value of get_stylesheet_directory_uri() alot, you could also set it to a short string variable to reuse it.

Comment: And I also found out that the function does NOT include a trailing slash, so the above code should be correct. The reason you don't want to use another function like get_bloginfo('tempate_url') is due to the fact that if your theme is a child theme then the parent theme URL will be returned rather than your child.

Comment: hmm this works good for templates but is there a method for when typing the image location in the admin area on a Page?